# Way to open popup in a new window

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, internet-explorer-8, dom-events

Is there any way to force IE8 to open new window only in a pop-up? I don't want to change the browser settings. I want to open it and throw Javascript `window.open()`. Firefox is opening it in a new window but IE8 is opening the same in a new tab. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** control whether a browser opens a window in a new tab or new window.

Although, one work around is to set height and width dimension in the call to `window.open()` alongwith disabling the addressbar and statusbar.

```
window.open ("http://www.example.com", "mywindow","status=0,toolbar=0,height=600,width=900");
```

It worked for my case, I'm not sure if this satisfies your question.

Comment: Make sure to not have spaces in the parms. Older browsers will ignore anything after a space

Answer (score 0):

hold a SHIFT button while you click on an Internet hyperlink on your browser screen. This will force the link to open in a new window